# How to use main function inside test function when unit testing Gin

Tags: unit-testing, go, go-gin

I want to unit test gin controller function.

```
package controllers

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/go-playground/assert/v2"
)

func TestGetDivisions(t *testing.T) {
    tt := []struct {
        Name         string
        EnterpriseID string
        Code         int
    }{
        {Name: "Enterprise id exists", EnterpriseID: "1", Code: 200},
        {Name: "Enterprise id cannot be string", EnterpriseID: "string", Code: 404},
    }
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    c, _ := gin.CreateTestContext(w)

    for _, tc := range tt {
        c.Params = []gin.Param{
            {
                Key:   "enterprise_id",
                Value: tc.EnterpriseID,
            },
        }
        GetDivisions(c) // Error from here
        assert.Equal(t, tc.Code, w.Code, tc.Name)
    }
}
```

Problem is, whenever I use GetDivision function inside a test file gives error like below:

```
--- FAIL: TestGetDivisions (0.00s)
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
    panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x28 pc=0x43c7438]
```

Cannot find where is a problem. Can I give test context to a function as a parameter?

And here is my GetDivisions handler:

```
// Get divisions of an enterprise by given id. Default id = "1"
func GetDivisions(c *gin.Context) {
    var divisions []models.Division

    if err := config.DB.Find(&divisions).Error; err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "divisions": divisions,
    })
}
```

Comment: please add the `GetDivisions` handler to the question

Comment: @blackgreen Added GetDivisions handler

Comment: Looks like the `divisions` slice is not properly initialized and is `nil` when you invoke `gin.H`.

Comment: @vtm11 Everything looks good, I tested it

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an error occurs in config.DB.Find(&divisions), because I think invalid memory error accurs when it reads from database and writes to variable... can you show the code of config.DB.Find(). (if it is on GitHub, you can send me link)

Comment: DB.Find() came from `gorm` itself, I think problem isn't there. I'm sure that GetDivisons() works fine. Actually we use it. Error came from testcontext.